# How do I randomize images and audio while making sure to keep divs attatched in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

This is the site in question: [driglight.com/Learn5.html](http://driglight.com/Learn5.html)

The purpose of this site is to click the audio and then choose which image you believe to be the correct representation of the note that was played.

I want to randomize the audio and answers every time the page is refreshed.
When the audio is randomized I need to make sure that the audio that is chosen has it's matching correct answer of an image also chosen and placed randomly among the answers. Also,when any possible answer image is clicked, a div will appear that says 'Good Job!' or 'incorrect'. So when the correct answer is randomized it will need to have the 'Good Job' div to follow it.

Here is the code in html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Learn</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom-styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/component.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.css">

   <script src="js/stuff.js"></script>
    <!-- <script  src="js/Timhasnoinput.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">activate Google Chrome Frame</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- This code is taken from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html -->
        <div class="header-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <div class="site-name">
                        <h1>Music Website</h1>
                    </div>




                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="menu">

                    <div class="navbar">
                        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                            <i class="fw-icon-th-list"></i>
                        </a>
                        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>


                                <li><a href="Learn.html">Learn</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <div class="mini-menu">
        <label>
      <select class="selectnav">
        <option value="#" selected="">Home</option>

        <option value="#">→ Hello</option>
        <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
        <option value="#">→ Another action</option>
        <option value="#">→ Something else here</option>
        <option value="#">About</option>
        <option value="#">Learn</option>
        <option value="#">Contact</option>
      </select>
      </label>
      </div>

        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container bg-white">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 ">
                    <div class="main-caption">
                        <h1>Music Website</h1>
                        <h6>Learning Music</h6>

                    </div>
                    <div class="Timmy2">
                                    <h4><a href="Learn4.html">< Lesson 2</a></h4>
                                    <h6></h6>
                                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container bg-white">

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="banner">
                    <div class="audiobuttonholder">
                    <div class="audioholder" style="padding-bottom:24px;">
                      <audio controls id="audio1">

                        hello
                        </audio> 
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttonholder"; style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 40px;"> 

                        </div>
                    <div class = "numberPage">
                    Pg. 3 Trebble Cleff
                    </div>
                        <div class = "control">
<ul>  
 <div id="div1"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px; 
margin-top: 40px;"  > 
 <img id=div1image imageC="incorrect.png" src="incorrect.png"></img>
 </div>
 <input type="image" id="myimage1" style="height:200px;width:200px;   
onclick="showDivOne()" /> 
 </ul>

                            <ul>
<div id="div2"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px;" > 
 <img id=div2image imageC="incorrect.png" src="incorrect.png" />
 </div>
<input type="image" id="myimage2" style="height:200px;width:200px; padding-
top:24px;" onclick="showDivTwo()"/>
</ul>

 <ul>
 <div id="div3"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px; 
 padding-top: 40px;" > 
 <img id=div3image imageC="incorrect.png" src="incorrect.png"></img>
 </div>
 <input type="image" id="myimage3" style="height:200px;width:200px;padding-
 top:24px;" onclick="showDivThree()"/>
 </ul>


 <ul> 
 <div id="div4"  style="display:none; float: right; margin-right: 120px; 
margin-top: 40px;" > 
 <img id=div4image imageC="incorrect.png" src="incorrect.png"></img>
 </div>
 <input type="image" id="myimage4" style="height:200px;width:200px;" 
onclick="showDivFour()" />
 </ul>











                        </div>
            </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

                       <div class="featured-images">
                        <ul class="grid effect-8" id="grid">
                          <li>
                            <div class="block">
                             <div class="Timmy2">
                                    <h4><a href="Learn3.html">< Lesson 2</a></h4>
                                    <h6></h6>
                                  </div>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                            <div class="block-content">

                                  <div class="user-info">

                                   <h4><a href="index.html">Home</a></h4>
                                   <h6> </h6>

                                   </div>

                                <div class="user-info">

                                    <h4><a href="Learn.html">Learn</a></h4>
                                    <h6> </h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="user-info">

                                   <h4><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></h4>
                                   <h6> </h6>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

            </div>
        </div>








   <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/imagesloaded.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/AnimOnScroll.js"></script>

<script>
  new AnimOnScroll( document.getElementById( 'grid' ), {
    minDuration : 0.4,
    maxDuration : 0.7,
    viewportFactor : 0.2
  } );
</script>
<script>
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
interval: 1800
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code in Javascript:

```
    function showDivFour() {
   document.getElementById('div4').style.display = "block";
}
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('welcomeDiv').style.display = "block";
}
function showDivOne() {
   document.getElementById('div1').style.display = "block";
}
function showDivTwo() {
   document.getElementById('div2').style.display = "block";
}
function showDivThree() {
   document.getElementById('div3').style.display = "block";
}




// THIS SHOULD BE THE BETTER ONE
var correctFileC = $('#div1image').attr("div_answer");
var correctFileC = $('#div2image').attr("div_answer");
var correctFileC = $('#div3image').attr("div_answer");
var correctFileC = $('#div4image').attr("div_answer");
var correctFile1 = $('#myimage1').attr("div_if");
var correctFile2 = $('#myimage2').attr("div_if");
var correctFile3 = $('#myimage3').attr("div_if");
var correctFile4 = $('#myimage4').attr("div_if");



var audio_1 = ["LowATrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","LowETrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3",
"LowGTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","MidBTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3",
"MidCTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3","MidDTrebbleCleffPianoVC.mp3"];

var rand_audio_1 = 
audio_1[Math.floor(Math.random()*audio_1.length)].getElementByName.
(audioholder.innerHTML(rand_audio_1);

function div_if(){
if(audio_1[0]){

    var R1 = ["myimage1","TrebbleCleffLowA.gif"],["myimage2","TrebbleCleffLowA.gif"],["myimage3","TrebbleCleffLowA.gif"],["myimage4","TrebbleCleffLowA.gif"];
    if[R1(var i=0; i<R1.length;i++).length=4];
} else if(audio_1[1]){

    var R2 = ["myimage1","LowE.gif"],["myimage2","LowE.gif"],["myimage3","LowE.gif"],["myimage4","LowE.gif"];
    if[R2(var i=0; i<R2.length;i++).length=4];
    do nothing
} else if(audio_1[2]){

    var R3 = ["myimage1","LowG.gif"],["myimage2","LowG.gif"],["myimage3","LowG.gif"],["myimage4","LowG.gif"]; 
    if[R3(var i=0; i<R3.length;i++).length=4];
    do nothing
} else if(audio_1[3]){

    var R4 = ["myimage1","MidB.gif"],["myimage2","MidB.gif"],["myimage3","MidB.gif"],["myimage4","MidB.gif"]; 
    if[R4(var i=0; i<R4.length;i++).length=4];
    do nothing
} else if(audio_1[4]){

    var R5 = ["myimage1","MidC.gif"],["myimage2","MidC.gif"],["myimage3","MidC.gif"],["myimage4","MidC.gif"]; 
    if[R5(var i=0; i<R5.length;i++).length=4];
    do nothing
    { else if(audio_1[5]){

    var R6 = ["myimage1","MidD.gif"],["myimage2","MidD.gif"],["myimage3","MidD.gif"],["myimage4","MidD.gif"];
    if[R6(var i=0; i<R6.length;i++).length=4];
    do nothing

} else if{
    L1.Push(R);
} else if{
    L1.Push(R1)
} else if{
    L1.Push(R2)
} else if{
    L1.Push(R3)
} else if{
    L1.Push(R4)
    }


function div_answer(){
if(R[0]){
    document.getElementById(div1).innerHTML(divC);
    divC.src='GoodJob.png'{
        else if(R[1]){
            document.getElementById(div2).innerHTML(divC);
            divC.src='GoodJob.png'
        }
        else if(R[2]){
            document.getElementById(div3).innerHTML(divC);
            divC.src='GoodJob.png'
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById(div4).innerHTML(divC);
            divC.src='GoodJob.png'
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code edit Obsidian Age! :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume every audio fragment will have an image? So with that in mind, you create a random index to select an audio fragment (which you already do). Why don't you store that index in a variable and associate the image fragment with it?

Another option would be to create an object. So you make your array with audiofragments and then you initialize a new JS object, and assign the names of the images to 'properties' with your audiofragment as key. Like this:

```
var images = {};
images[audioname] = image-name; 
***Do this for each audiofragment of course***
```

That way you can just ask the image from your images-object, using the property audioname.

Comment: The audio and images will be placed in separate divs. The audio itself will have to go through a randomization for which one will be chosen to be placed in the audio div, and the images will go through randomization to be placed in one of the many image divs. How would I use this system while keeping the randomization and making sure that the audio and image pairs remain intact?

Comment: You can make two arrays, one with images, one with audiofragments. You'll need to randomize both of them.
By using the last method (the javascript Object) you can effectively 'link' the images to the corresponding audiofragment. (or you'll probably need to link the audio to the images). Whenever the user clicks an image, you can use this object to check the corresponding audio file and check if that is the current audio file in your div.

Comment: I don't know if you're into other code languages but it's comparable to a hashMap for Java or a Dictionary in C#. (key and value)

Comment: I edited the javascript code in an attempt to get closer to the goal of getting it to work. I think that now, all I need to do is figure out how to get it to post to the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

When the page renders, place some value inside the attributes for the images or div:

```html
<img id=myimage data-audio-file="xyz123.mp3" src="...." />
<div data-audio-file="xyz123.mp3" src="...." >My Content</div>
```

Read the attribute out when it's time to take some action:

`var correctFile = $('#myimage').attr("data-audio-file");`

Comment: So basically this means that I can put any audio file into the variable data-audio-file and its source into src because the .attr will place what is inside correctFile in the place of the mp3 and its source that I first put in?

Comment: Yes. you can add related attributes for filenames, primary keys, whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was a bit confused by the src being "..." but I guess its basically the same meaning at "xyz123.mp3".

Comment: Would it be possible to place div_if as an attribute? This is really confusing. I'm not sure how to place the variable which holds the randomly selected div placement for an image, and the image, into an attribute or if that's even possible. Where do I go to know what 'related attributes' are? When i search I see things like width, color,and position change upon button press, mouse click, and others for an already known image. My image isn't known, neither is the div it's going to be in, but I have the variable which will pick those.

Comment: I edited the code to try and explain better on what it is I am trying to do.